# `Tensorflow` compilation failure, `absl` symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gcc, compilation, clang

I have been trying to compile `tensorflow v2.*` for the last week. For possible CPU inference performance optimisation.

environment:

```bash
OS: ubuntu 18.04
compiler: gcc-v9.3.0/v9.4.0
target tensorflow verison: tensorflow v 2.10.0/2.11.0/2.12.0
bazel version: v 5.1.1/v 5.3.0/ v 5.3.0 respectively
```

command to compile:

```bash
env CC=/home/echeng/GCC-9.3.0/bin/gcc CXX=/home/echeng/GCC-9.3.0/bin/g++ bazel build --local_cpu_resources=1 --config=opt --copt="-Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized" --copt="-Wno-error" //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so --verbose_failures
```

The compilation can run fine until about the 10000th target. and then it stops, complaining that an `absl` symbol is missing:

```bash
ERROR: /home/echeng/tmp/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/BUILD:673:22: Executing genrule //tensorflow/cc:io_ops_genrule failed: (Exit 127): bash failed: error executing command
  (cd /home/echeng/.cache/bazel/_bazel_echeng/2791709de7ed8b410670694aec878ce9/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/home/echeng/global_files/lib:/home/echeng/global_files/lib \
    PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/echeng/.cargo/bin:/home/echeng/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/echeng/global_files/bin/datagrip/DataGrip/bin/:/home/echeng/third_party_utils/diff_so_fancy:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux,:/home/echeng/.local/bin:/home/echeng/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/bin:/with/tetrion/root/bin:/usr/lib/icecc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/with/tetrion/scripts:/snap/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/home/echeng/.fzf/bin:/home/echeng/global_files/bin/:/home/echeng/global_files/bin/ \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/home/echeng/anaconda3/envs/lstm/bin/python3 \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/home/echeng/anaconda3/envs/lstm/lib/python3.8/site-packages \
    TF2_BEHAVIOR=1 \
  /bin/bash bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/cc/io_ops_genrule.genrule_script.sh)
# Configuration: 73b22a0b8b02d57837db5cbfd145ac5b2c1678d8161822f496527a1416447639
# Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/cc/ops/io_ops_gen_cc: symbol lookup error: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/cc/ops/io_ops_gen_cc: undefined symbol: _ZN4absl12lts_2022062318container_internal11kEmptyGroupE
Target //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.235s, Critical Path: 0.38s
INFO: 30 processes: 30 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

This happens on all the above versions I mentioned, using bezel single or multicore compilation modes.

I however managed to locate the symbol in `bazel-bin/external/com_google_absl/absl/container/_objs/raw_hash_set/raw_hash_set.o`:

```bash
$ nm raw_hash_set.o

                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 r .LC0
0000000000000010 r .LC1
0000000000000000 R _ZN4absl12lts_2022062318container_internal11kEmptyGroupE
0000000000000000 W _ZN4absl12lts_2022062318container_internal19find_first_non_fullIvEENS1_8FindInfoEPKNS1_6ctrl_tEmm
0000000000000000 T _ZN4absl12lts_2022062318container_internal21ShouldInsertBackwardsEmPKNS1_6ctrl_tE
0000000000000000 T _ZN4absl12lts_2022062318container_internal37ConvertDeletedToEmptyAndFullToDeletedEPNS1_6ctrl_tEm
0000000000000000 u _ZZN4absl12lts_2022062318container_internal10RandomSeedEvE7counter
```

Comment: What's the series of commands you used to setup the build? Alternatively, try the Docker build?

Comment: @Darius Oh yeah, thank you very much! I just tried docker + llvm + clang 16.0.6 and it it worked !

Comment: @Darius But here is the problem again: looks like `libtensorflow.so` links to GLIBC_2.33 and GLIBC_2.34 then. I don't have that on my own system. So it fails at runtime this time? Is it possible that I pack the `GLIBC` inside `libtensorflow.so`, I ask this because I notice the distributed `libtensorflow.so` is much larger in size compare to my compiled version.

Comment: can you post your error, as well as glibc version on your system?